# Error Attaching IAM Role to an Instance Profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, karpenter

I am trying to attach an IAM role to an instance profile for aws karpenter to be able to provision nodes on my behalf. I have already created the role, `role-karpenter`, from the console.

**Below is the terraform script:**

```
data "aws_iam_role" "karpenter_node_group_role" {
  name = "role-karpenter"
}

resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "karpenter" {
  name = "KarpenterNodeInstanceProfile"
  role = data.aws_iam_role.karpenter_node_group_role.name
}
```

**This is the Error I am getting:**

```bash
removing role arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/role-karpenter from IAM instance profile KarpenterNodeInstanceProfile-cluster: ValidationError: The specified value for roleName is invalid. It must contain only alphanumeric characters and/or the following: +=,.@_-
│   status code: 400, request id: 7e631745-e7cb-4542-b19f-2b3872c8cbc3
```

**Options I have tried:**
I have used all these different terraform attribute references for the role

```
# name attribute
role = data.aws_iam_role.karpenter_node_group_role.name

# id attribute
role = data.aws_iam_role.karpenter_node_group_role.id

# arn attribute
role = data.aws_iam_role.karpenter_node_group_role.arn
```

Comment: Did you run `terraform plan` prior to `terraform apply`?

Comment: Hey @MarkoE Yes I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for me was to remove the resource from the state file and rerun it again

```bash
terraform state rm module.eks.aws_iam_instance_profile.karpenter
```

Then

```bash
terraform plan && terraform apply
```